# How to select running shoes for rainy weather

Tags: running, running-shoes, shoes

I am a newbie runner and need your advice for good running shoes to buy. I have some running shoes but they are slippery. Any good advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how this is opinion based (re: close votes). It's pretty concrete to determine shoes for cross country vs track running. Tread patterns and rubber types perform differently in wet vs dry conditions, and some shoes dry quicker and others stay waterlogged forever.

Answer (score 2):

So at the end of the day there is not a ton you can do. It's all about static friction and no matter what if you add water as a layer between the surface you're running on and your shoes the coefficient of static friction will be decreased. What you can do is look into trail running shoes. They are intentionally built with more support and traction for running on muddy trail surfaces. There are several brands that all claim this and they will achieve your purpose.

Comment: +1 I use trailschoes on the ice-covered walkways during winter aswell.